# Angular + TypeScript + External Modules. How to maintain type information across files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, commonjs

I'm using Angular 1.4, TypeScript 1.6, and CommonJS external modules.

I have three files in this module:

```
paginator.module.ts
paginator.service.ts
paginator.controller.ts
```

`paginator.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import PaginatorService = require('./paginator.service');
import PaginatorCtrl = require('./paginator.controller');

var Paginator = angular.module('paginator', [])
  .service('pageService', PaginatorService)
  .controller('pageCtrl', PaginatorCtrl);
```

Here's `paginator.service.ts`:

```
class PaginatorService {
    currentPage: number;
    pageCount: number;
    pages: Array<Array<any>>;

    constructor() {
      this.currentPage = 0;
    }
  }

export = PaginatorService;
```

In `paginator.controller.ts`, I inject `pageService` along with `$scope` using dependency injection, and I expect to see type information when I give it a type of `PaginatorService`.

```
class PaginatorController {
  scope: ng.IScope;
  pageService: PaginatorService;

  /**
   * @param  $scope
   * @param  pageService
   */
  constructor($scope: ng.IScope, pageService: PaginatorService) {
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.pageService = pageService;
  }
 export = PaginatorController;
```

However, I receive the following error in atom-typescript:

`TS Error: Cannot find name 'PaginatorService'.`

## What I've tried

- Adding another import statement in `paginator.controller.js` file resolves the issue (i.e. `import PaginatorService = require('./paginator.service');`). However, this seems redundant as I've already `require()`d this service when setting up my Angular module.
- I tried using `tsc --declaration` on `paginator.service.js` to generate a declaration file, which you can view below, but it didn't resolve the issue.

**Autogenerated d.ts file**

```
declare class PaginatorService {
    currentPage: number;
    pageCount: number;
    pages: Array<Array<any>>;
    constructor();
}
export = PaginatorService;
```

- Modifying this declaration file to declare a *module* (ambient declaration?) seemed to work, but manually doing this for the 100+ Angular services I need to migrate to CommonJS syntax makes this approach problematic.

My question is this: **What is a recommended pattern for using CommonJS + Angular + TypeScript to require the correct modules and then let Angular's dependency injection take over from there, especially across files?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> TS Error: Cannot find name 'PaginatorService'.

You are doing

```
export class PaginatorService
```

You need to import it as

## ES6

```
import {PaginatorService} from "./paginatorService";
```

or

## Old style

```
import paginatorService = require("./paginatorService"); 
import PaginatorService = paginatorService.PaginatorService;
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I'm actually using `export = PaginatorService` syntax, so that it doesn't create a namespace (e.g. `foo.Foo`).  

My core question is, do I need to have an import statement in both `paginator.module.ts` to notify AngularJS of the module's existence AND in the `paginator.controller.ts` simply to have type information about `PaginatorService`? Or is there a pattern to require it once at the AngularJS module level, and then rely on Angular's dependency injection from there?

Comment: @JonathanGuerrera updated the answer. Just replaced `foo` with a verbose `PaginatorService` :)

Comment: @JonathanGuerrera `Or is there a pattern to require it once at the AngularJS module level, and then rely on Angular's dependency injection from there` You need both. Blame angular. Move to react :P

Comment: @basarat the need to require/import paginatorService in both the controller and module files isn't because of Angular. It's because of typescript. You'll have the same issue with React if you're using typescript and external modules.

Comment: @Jupo not true. React doesn't have a DI system out of the box. Its just modules. That said, it was a joke